# Conditional execution in Ant

Tags: ant

I have a target, that is executed if `my_step==true`:

```
<target name="pre-compile" if="my_step">
...
</target>
```

But I want to make that pre-compile target available regardless of the value of `my_step`, so that I could execute my action manually using `ant do_my_step`:

```
<target name"-do_my_step">
...
</target>
```

Question. How can I run make pre-compile execute -do_my_step target?
That is, if property my_step is true, then pre-compile step will execute -do_my_step target.
Obviously, I could simply copy-paste contents of -do_my_step target into pre-compile target, but I want to keep my target cleanly separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target names with prefix '-' are a common practice to make the target somewhat 'private' as it's impossible to call it via commandline. `ant -f yourbuildfile.xml -yourprivatetarget` won't work as ant commandline interface uses leading '-' for options. So strip the leading  '-' from your target name to call it via `ant -f yourbuildfile.xml do_my_step`
Also consider :
"..Question. How can I run make pre-compile execute -do_my_step target? .."
Ant has [antcall](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) task for calling a target within the same buildscript. But antcall should be avoided because it opens a new project scope (so it needs more memory and will slow down your build) and breaks the dependency chain which is normally built via `<target name="..." depends"=...">` .
 `antcall` is superfluous since ant 1.6 introduced [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) for that purpose (reuse of functionality).

Comment: I cannot change names of targets, they have to be as-is, since I override existing target names. Regarding antcall. How can i call some random target using antcall? I'm absolutely ZERO when it comes to ant... all I can tell so far about it is that xml-based make is pretty bad idea ;)

Comment: rtfm ;) http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html, xml based = bad idea => seconded - but you'll get used to it :)

Comment: I really don't like too much xml overall to get used to anything xml based ;) I simply need to modify some ant-based scripts and then forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<target name="pre-compile" if="my_step" depends="-do_my_step">
...
</target>
```

When `pre-compile` is called, it will run `-do_my_step` before.

Comment: doesn't work. It runs everything as if there was no `if="my_step"` in the target specification. In other words, -do_my_step always runs

Comment: Ah, ok... the if="xxx" part means that target will be executed if xxx property is set (to any value, including `false`). How can I fix it?

Comment: If using ant >= 1.8 use property expansion, means use => if="${xxx}" and xxx must have boolean value true to get target executed.

Comment: @Rebse: I use 1.8.4. I tested more, and it looks that regardless of the `if` it still executes -do_my_step even if pre-compile target isn't executed.

Comment: from ant manual http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html = Important: the if and unless attributes only enable or disable the target to which they are attached. They do not control whether or not targets that a conditional target depends upon get executed. In fact, they do not even get evaluated until the target is about to be executed, and all its predecessors have already run

Comment: @Rebse exactly, that's what my tests show. I need to use `if="${my_step}"` in combination with antcall